# Python Function, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
def numvaluesindf(inputfile):
    import pandas as pd
    inputdf = pd.read_csv(inputfile)
    uniquevalues =inputdf.nunique()
    numvalues = inputdf.count()
    print ('Unique Values')
    print (uniquevalues)
    print ('Count')
    print (numvalues)
    numvaluesindf('test.csv')
```

Question: How would run my function. When i run it nothing happens.I get this error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File test.csv does not exist: 'test.csv'

Comment: you need to add a return statement at the end of the function.

Comment: @gnahum OP is printing the values inside function.

Comment: call it using `numvaluesindf(filename)`

Comment: @Kevin python correct indentation of your code

Comment: @Kevin python It seems that there is no file named `test.csv` in the directory that you are working on

Answer (score 0):

```
def numvaluesindf(inputfile):
    import pandas as pd
    inputdf = pd.read_csv(inputfile)
    uniquevalues =inputdf.nunique()
    numvalues = inputdf.count()
    print ('Unique Values')
    print (uniquevalues)
    print ('Count')
    print (numvalues)
    numvaluesindf('test.csv')
```

The function call `numvaluesindf('test.csv')` is indented to the same level as your function making your function recursive. Unindent the last line like so:

```
def numvaluesindf(inputfile):
    import pandas as pd
    inputdf = pd.read_csv(inputfile)
    uniquevalues =inputdf.nunique()
    numvalues = inputdf.count()
    print ('Unique Values')
    print (uniquevalues)
    print ('Count')
    print (numvalues)

numvaluesindf('test.csv')
```

Comment: ok that might be it, but im pretty sure its not someone else in my directory

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
def numvaluesindf(inputfile): 
    import pandas as pd 
    inputdf = pd.read_csv(inputfile)
    uniquevalues =inputdf.nunique()
    numvalues = inputdf.count()
    print ('Unique Values')
    print (uniquevalues)
    print ('Count')
    print (numvalues)


numvaluesindf('test.csv')
```

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File test.csv does not exist: 'test.csv'

Comment: is there a file named `test.csv` in the same directory as your python file? @kevinpython

Comment: `test.csv` should be the relative or absolute path to the csv file. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying to call the function form the function block. Its indented to the same level as your function, hence it does not work as expected,
Please try the below code.

```
import pandas as pd

def numvaluesindf(inputfile):
    inputdf = pd.read_csv(inputfile)
    uniquevalues = inputdf.nunique()
    numvalues = inputdf.count()
    print('Unique Values')
    print(uniquevalues)
    print('Count')
    print(numvalues)

numvaluesindf('test.csv')
```